# Make static program

Tags: c++, static, makefile

when I compile some program to work on server, I just add to g++ line -static flag, then I can run it without any library on external PC. Is there a way to compile this way more complex source? I know I can add -static to CFLAGS in Makefile, but it is not enough - after trying to send **xdotools** to server via scp, ssh protocol says it cannot open this folder (wtf?).

Comment: You also need to link with `-static`. Can you show more of your build process?

Comment: Okay, good point. Should I paste whole build output? It is long. Just download xdotools source and add -static to CFLAGS+= -gcc=99 (or something).

Comment: Check the linker flags too.

Comment: And watch out for any sub-libraries that get built as part of the whole program.

Comment: You need to be way more specific here :P

Comment: I'll try to take a look the next time I'm at a computer.

Comment: What says it cannot open the folder? That doesn't sound like a linker related error. That sounds like a path problem with the scp command. You need to be **much** more clear about what you are trying to do, what you have done, what problems you are having and where you are having them.